# Write a bash script to check if process is responding in x seconds?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How can I write a script to check if a process is taking a number of seconds to respond, and if over that number kill it?

I've tried the timeout command, but the problem is it is a source dedicated sever, and when i edit it's bash script:

```
    HL=./srcds_linux
    echo "Using default binary: $HL"
```

and change it to timeout 25 ./srcds_linux and run it as root it won't run the server:
ERROR: Source Engine binary '' not found, exiting

So assuming that I can't edit the servers bash script, is there a way to create a script that can check if any program, not executed w/ the script is timing out in x seconds?

Comment: How do you distinguish between a program that runs fine and one that hangs ? In your case, if the program runs, does it exit after certain seconds ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I would see if my server is crashed, but still running. For example, if people made my server lag so much that it is unjoinable. When people do this, the console is still running, but I cant type anything in and it takes >25 seconds for the terminal to register my keys. So is there a way to (outside the program) check if this delay is present?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that you're changing the script wrong.

If you're looking at [this script](http://downloads.sourceserver.info/testing/poc_ssh/orig/srcds_run), the logic basically goes:

```
HL=./srcds_linux
if ! test -f "$HL"
then
  echo "Command not found"
fi
$HL
```

It sounds like you're trying to set `HL="timeout 25 ./srcds_linux"`. This will cause the file check to fail.

The somewhat more correct way is to change the invocation, not the file to invoke:

```
HL=./srcds_linux
if ! test -f "$HL
then
  echo "Command not found"
fi
timeout 25 $HL
```

`timeout` kills the program if it takes too long, though. It doesn't care whether the program is responding to anything, just that it takes longer than 25 seconds doing it.

If the program appears to hang, you could e.g. check whether it stops outputting data for 25 seconds:

```
your_command_to_start_your_server | while read -t 25 foo; do echo "$foo"; done
echo "The command hasn't said anything for 25 seconds, killing it!"
pkill ./srcds_linux
```

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, $HL was just the file check, I found further down the file check where the execute the command with $HL, and put timeout 25 before it, but this makes my server go really slow and crash. Any ideas?

Comment: As described in the answer, `timeout 25` will make the server die after 25 seconds. The answer suggests that this doesn't sound like what you want, and suggests an alternate approach based on checking whether the command outputs anything in 25 seconds.

Comment: -Ah cool, so if I do: ./srcds_linux | while read -t 25 foo; do echo "$foo"; done pkill ./srcds_linux   -  this checks if it has said something in the last 25 seconds & kills if not? Also, do I need root for pkill if the process was not started by root?

Comment: Yes. And no, a user who starts a process doesn't need root access to stop it.

Comment: Thank you that will work, but I'm wondering is there any other easier way to check if it's going slow, for example for this I would need to do print("restart check") on my server ever 25 seconds for it to work. This will work but I'm wondering is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Well, you asked this on a programming forum under the tags linux, bash and scripting, so not surprisingly you got a general answer using bash scripting on linux (this solution doesn't care whether you're running `srcds_linux` or `cdrecord` or `rsync`). Perhaps a Source Engine forum could suggest Source Engine specific ways of monitoring the server?

Comment: Right, well I'll just use this option for now, but when I try to do read -t it says illegal option -t

Comment: Make sure you're using `bash` and not `sh`. The first line in the file should be `#!/bin/bash` and you should run it with either `./yourfile` or `bash yourfile`, but not `sh yourfile`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually ended up using a server script to delete all laggy physics objects if no players can join. The problem was the script executing ./srcds_linux was a .sh not .bash so I couldn't use read -t